# Hiding wordpress admin bar during development

Tags: wordpress, admin

I created and added this to my footer.php file to try and create something that would 'hide' my admin bar while i was developing because it was getting in the way. Can someone else test this and tell me why it's not working?

```
<?php global $user_ID; if( $user_ID ) : ?>
<?php if( current_user_can('level_10') ) : ?>

<!-- ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? -->
<div class="hidetheadminbar">ADMIN MENU</div>
<style type="text/css">
      .hidetheadminbar {
            width: 140px;
            height: 48px;
            line-height: 48px;
            background: #BE0000;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
            box-shadow: 0 -1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 999;
            left: -80px;
            top: 45%;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
            -moz-transition: all 500ms;
            -ms-transition: all 500ms;
            transition: all 500ms;
            text-align: center;
            color: #FFF;
      }
      .hidetheadminbar:hover {
            left: -50px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
            -moz-transition: all 500ms;
            -ms-transition: all 500ms;
            transition: all 500ms;
      }
      .gone {
            display: none;  
      }
      .zero {
            position: relative;
            top: -32px; 
      }
      </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".hidetheadminbar").click(function() {
              jQuery("#wpadminbar").toggleClass("gone");
              jQuery("html").toggleClass("zero");
            });
            jQuery(".hidetheadminbar").trigger("click");
          });
</script> 
<!-- ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? -->

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can disable the admin bar from the backend for each user account.

Comment: I know. But it became a pain having to get to the backend without having it there. so i just wanted a little inconspicuous button to toggle it.

Comment: check the console for js errors, the above should work but you may be using jquery before its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a conditional test when u add `wp_footer();`in your footer.php